# Filtras registros via datetime e traze-los entre uma data inicial e final

Tags: mysql, datetime, procedure, stored-procedures

[image: Tabela saldo]

Tenho a tabela saldo, que sempre ao executar uma procedure, é gerado um novo registro na mesma, podendo ter vários registro no mesmo dia...
Porém, ao fazer uma consulta, eu quero trazer apenas o último registro de cada dia, então fiz assim:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_balanco_diario(IN var_data DATETIME)
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM saldo
WHERE DATE(data_mov_saldo) = var_data
ORDER BY data_mov_saldo DESC
LIMIT 1;
END //
```

Porém, agora preciso fazer essa consulta trazendo os dados entre um intervalo de datas, ou seja, trazer os dados entre uma data inicial e uma data final, mas trazendo apenas o último registro de cada dia, como na procedure acima.

Os campos da tabelas estão demonstrados na imagem.

Comment: já resolveu seu problema ?

Answer (score 1):

tente assim:

```
SELECT 
    entradas            AS ENTRADAS,
    saidas              AS SAIDAS,
    saldo               AS SALDO,
    MAX(data_mov_saldo) AS DATA 
    FROM saldo 
        WHERE data_mov_saldo  BETWEEN '10/10/2016' AND '20/10/2016'
            GROUP BY data_mov_saldo,entradas,saidas,saldo
```

Answer (score 0):

na cláusula `where` você coloca `WHERE column_data_name BETWEEN data_value1 AND data_value2;`
exemplo

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_data BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '30/01/2010';
```

Comment: quanto a parte dos ultimos registros por dia veja se [isso](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro é preciso criar uma subquery que retorne a data/hora da última movimentação de cada dia do intervalo solicitado.

O exemplo abaixo mostra qual deveria ser o resultado da subquery com base nos valores contidos em`data_mov_saldo`:

```
saldo                         resultado da subquery
data_mov_saldo                dia          ultima_mov
03.01.2017 10:00:00           03.01.2017   03.01.2017 11:00:00
03.01.2017 11:00:00           04.01.2017   04.01.2017 13:00:00
04.01.2017 12:00:00           05.01.2017   05.01.2017 15:00:00
04.01.2017 13:00:00
05.01.2017 14:00:00
05.01.2017 15:00:00
```

Então, basta fazer o JOIN do resultado da subquery com a tabela `saldo` conforme a query abaixo:

```
select * 
  from (select date(data_mov_saldo) as dia
              ,max(data_mov_saldo) as ultima_mov
         from saldo
        where date(data_mov_saldo) between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-10'
        group by date(data_mov_saldo)) as mov 
  join saldo on saldo.data_mov_saldo = mov.ultima_mov;
```

**Para testar**

Criei um exemplo que roda online em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a41cff/1